# matplotlib-Two different colorsets for one colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, colorbar

I am doing some plots and I have problems which I can't solve, why I wanted to ask the community. I didn't find the problem here.

[How my graphic looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzBD.png)

I want to change in the graphic mainly two things.

1. I want to have to different coloursets in the colourbar and not just one. For example one which has red a yellow colours for values smaller than zero and the other one with different green colours for values which are above zero. The aim is to see clearly the difference for zero. Do you a way two implement two differen colour sets in one colorbar?
2. I think it's handy to change for the quick overview of the graphic to change the colourbar from fluently changing colours according to the values, to a colourbar has one specific colour for a range of values. That picture underlines my question :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvuJM.png

This code produces the graphic [How my graphic looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzBD.png) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    divnorm = colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-30000, vcenter=-15000, vmax=200
    cax=ax.pcolormesh(Z,cmap="YlGnBu",norm=divnorm )
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)

    #setting up right values for axis
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(x)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(y)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(list(map(int, list(np.round(x)))))
    ax.set_yticklabels(list(map(int, list(np.round(x)))))
```

Comment: Please keep posts to one question.  Q1: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html. For question 2 not clear if you want the data with a continuous map but the colorbar with discrete or both discrete.  I’d suggest if the colorbar is discrete for the data to be discrete, in which cas le you can use a boundary norm.

Comment: For the discrete colorbar you probably want to use `ax.contourf()` instead of `ax.pcolormesh()`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I solved my problem